# Recommendation fo Coredata/NSTableView filtered, sorted + AGGREGATION (groupBy)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I'm developing an Objective-C Coredata (SQLite), NSPersistentDocument based application with these requirements:

1. Simple model: 50-60K records imported from CSV with +30 fields
   each.
2. DOES NOT NEED support to write/add/delete records.
3. **NEEDED Strong support to "show/view" the information filtered,
   sorted, and GROUPED (aggregation),**

Able to group records as in a request similar to:

```
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:…]
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:…]
```

***My test OPTION 1***

I've used an NSArrayController bound to the Coredata Entity and NSTableView

- It Works.
- Advantages: Few code needed, does the fetching and can set
  a Filter Predicate and Sort Descriptor.
- Disadvantage: Doesn't support aggregation of
  records, not possible to add to its fetch request the
  additional information to groupBy.

***My test OPTION 2***

Fetch programatically, leave the results in an NSArray of NSDictionary's and use the NSArrayController bound to the array class and NSTableView

- Works.
- Advantage: It supports what I want. Doing the Fetch request myself I can use filter predicate, sort descriptors AND AGGREGATION (groupBy).
- Disadvantage: I guess it's not really efficient.

Leaving result in an nsarray of nsdictionary's everytime I change filter/sort/groupby options sounds like a non efficient way of doing it. Here is the result on the NSArray, as you can see the keys get repeated on each record, consuming memory and cpu cycles...

```
{
    {
        "f_01_Type" = "typeA";
        "f_02_Status" = "statusX";
        :
        "f_32_Period" = "2013010102";
    },
    :
     {
        "f_01_Type" = "typeF";
        "f_02_Status" = "statusU";
        :
        "f_32_Period" = "2009011102";
    }
}
```

What's would be your recommended solution? any other idea to explore?

Thanks
Luis